# Wicket AjaxCheckBox with Custom DateTables

Tags: wicket

I am using wicket 1.4 version and am playing around with the datatables and ajax checkboxes:

I can render the checkboxes on the html. When I click on the checkox, ajax onUpdate method is also getting invoked but its not giving me a proper value for the selected checkbox i.e. this.getModelValue() always is picking the first value of the row of the table.

What is that I am missing here?

```
add(getMyDynamicTable("myTable", provider, 10));

protected CustomDataTable<MyClass> getMyDynamicTable(String tableId, Provider provider, int numRows)    {

    final List<IColumn<MyClass>> myCloumns = new ArrayList<>();

    myCloumns.add(new AbstractColumn<MyClass>(new ResourceModel(
            "isSelected")) {

        @Override
        public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<MyClass>> item,
                String componentId, IModel<MyClass> rowModel) {
            final MyClass myclass = rowModel.getObject();

            CheckBoxPanel checkBoxPanel = new CheckBoxPanel(componentId, new PropertyModel<Boolean>(myclass, "isSelectedForRefund"));
            item.add(checkBoxPanel);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSortable() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String getSortProperty(){
            return "isSelected";
        }
    });

    return new CustomDataTable<MyClass>(tableId, myCloumns, provider, numRows, true);
 }

 class CheckBoxPanel extends Panel{

    private static final String ID_CHECK = "checkBox";

    private AjaxCheckBox field;

    private IModel model;

    public IModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(IModel modelObject) {
        this.model = modelObject;
    }

    public CheckBoxPanel(String id, IModel<Boolean> model) {
        super(id, model);
        System.out.println("clicked here "+ model.toString());
        setModel(model);
        field = new AjaxCheckBox(ID_CHECK, model) {

            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                target.addComponent(field);
                if(this.getModelValue().equals("true")) {
                    System.out.println("Selected");
                }
                else if(this.getModelValue().equals("false")) {
                    System.out.println("UnSelected");
                }

            }
        };
        field.setMarkupId(id);
        field.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier (ID_CHECK, id));
        field.setOutputMarkupId(true);


        add(field);
    }

    public CheckBoxPanel(String id) {
        this(id, new Model());
    }


 }
```

On my html, I have used the datatable tag

```
  <table class="dataview" cellspacing="0" wicket:id="myTable">[table]</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your checkboxes have the same markup id. 
This confuses the JavaScript responsible for collecting the value for the Ajax submit. It uses `document.getElementById('theId').value` and this always points to the first element in the page with that id.

You need to remove `field.setMarkupId(id);` or use unique ids for all checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for this, Damn I missed this bit!!. I accept this as a correct answer. Thanks again. Cheers!